# How to check whether a target is an aliased target in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm writing an CMake function which accepts a target name as an argument. I would like to detect whether it is static library type or shared library type, and if it is shared library, copy it to specified directory.

I can correctly handle targets that created via `add_executable()`, `add_library()` that directly gives source code. I can handle them with:

```
if(TARGET ${targetName})
   message(STATUS "this is an ordinary target")
endif()
```

**There are imported-and-aliased-targets**, but I can't determine them. I would like to use

```
if(ALIASES_TARGET ${targetName})
  message(STATUS "this is an aliases target")
endif()
```

But this didn't work.

N.B. CMake system will create some "garbage coding" named targets, seems like representing semicolon chars `;`, which I will ignore.

How can I determine if an given target name is an aliased target?

```
function(my_fancy_function targetName dstDir)
  if(TARGET ${targetName})
     message(STATUS "this is an ordinary target")
  endif()

  if(ALIASES_TARGET ${targetName}) # how to change this line?
    message(STATUS "this is an aliases target")
  endif()
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `ALIASED_TARGET` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ALIASED_TARGET.html). From the docs:

> If this is an Alias Target, this property contains the name of the target aliased.

Ex.

```
get_property(aliased_target TARGET "${targetName}" PROPERTY ALIASED_TARGET)
if("${aliased_target}" STREQUAL "")
  # is not an alias
else()
  # is an alias
endif()
```